# Use entityManager in a single repository

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa

I use spring-data-jpa to access my data. I need a way to detach an Object and store it as a new database row. My approach is currently to add a `detach` method to the repository, but for that, I need a `EntityManager`. And I haven't found a (nice) way of obtaining it... Any ideas?

```
@Repository
public interface InteractionRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Interaction, Long>,
                DetatchableItemRepository{}


public interface DetatchableItemRepository {
    void detach(Interaction clone);
}


public class DetatchableItemRepositoryImpl implements DetatchableItemRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public void detach(Interaction clone) {
        em.detach(clone);
        clone.id=null;
        em.persist(clone);

    }
}
```

However, spring dies with this error:

- Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interactionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property detach found for type Interaction!
- Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property detach found for type Interaction!

Answer (score 0):

you use wrong name convention for custom repository , try this :

```
 public interface DetatchableItemRepositoryCustom {
        void detach(Interaction clone);
    }


public interface DetatchableItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Interaction, Long>,
                                        DetatchableItemRepositoryCustom {

 }

 public class DetatchableItemRepositoryImpl implements DetatchableItemRepositoryCustom  {
 }
```

spring data use name convention for custom repository and main repository.(see about name [Adding custom behavior to single repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour))

If you have some SomeRepository , that extends some base spring data  repository , and want to add custom behavior then it should be like :

```
    interface SomeRepositoryCustom{
       someMethod();
    }     
    //XXXRepository - any base spring data repository
    interface SomeRepository extends<T ,ID> extend XXXRepository , SomeRepositoryCustom {
         .......
    }

    public class ARepositoryImpl implement SomeRepositoryCustom{
      @Overide
      someMethod(){
        ....
    }
```